# Label Clearcase View from Hudson

Tags: hudson, clearcase, hudson-plugins

Is there any way to label a paticular Clearcase view through the Hudson tool itself?

(i.e. with Perforce there is an option to "Label This Build").

Answer (score 0):

Not sure (I usually delegate that to an external script).
[`CleartoolExec`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/jvnet/hudson/plugins/clearcase/1.2.1/clearcase-1.2.1-javadoc.jar!/hudson/plugins/clearcase/ClearToolExec.html) does have actually a [`mklabel`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jvnet.hudson.plugins/clearcase/1.2.1/hudson/plugins/clearcase/ClearToolExec.java#ClearToolExec.mklabel%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) method, but again I am not sure how it is used by the current [Hudson ClearCase plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/ClearCase+Plugin?showChildren=false).